# время в ISO 8601

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно вызвать API передав туда время в формате ISO 8601
https://proxy.webshare.io/docs/api/#aggregate-stats
Перепробовал несколько библиотек включая встроенный new Date().toISOString()
но судя по всему не смог удовлетворить требования API по формированию даты/время.

В примере timestamp (в текстовом виде) формируется следующим образом:

```
"timestamp__lte":"2022-09-09T23:34:00.095501-07:00",
```

Я нигде не смог найти описания что такое `.095501-07:00` и как его сформировать

Дайте пожалуйста ссылку на описание ISO 8601 или может быть знаете библиотеку для javascript которая может форматировать timestamp таким образом?

P.S. стандарт я нашел, но платить за него 166 франков я не готов:
https://www.iso.org/standard/70907.html

P.P.S нашел еще тут
https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

если верить w3.org - то получается что "095501" - это дробная часть секунд а "-07:00" - это часовой пояс

Comment: Микросекунды и смещение относительно UTC

Comment: Однако toISOString тоже возвращает корректную ISO 8601 строку, которая должна подойти. Так что можно предположить, что проблема в кривом API, которое нарушает свою собственную документацию. Ну или вы просто используете API неправильно и проблема вообще не во времени

Comment: Скорее всего API кривое. Я сейчас пытаюсь понять что такое ```.095501-07:00``` и как его сформировать самому

Comment: Не часовой пояс, а смещение. Это принципиальная разница, которую важно понимать

Comment: "Не часовой пояс, а смещение" - Вы могли бы несколько подробнее пояснить ? Мне это очень нужно